# Map objects with matching owner

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I have this array of objects in a react component and want to map only those whose owner is logged in the website

```
const moles = [
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #001', image: Welthy1, Owner: 'Luis', id: 1 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #002', image: Welthy2, Owner: 'Pepe', id: 2 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #003', image: Welthy3, Owner: 'July', id: 3 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #004', image: Welthy4, Owner: 'Pepe', id: 4 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #005', image: Welthy5, Owner: 'Lola', id: 5 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #006', image: Welthy6, Owner: 'Luis', id: 6 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #007', image: Welthy7, Owner: 'Raul', id: 7 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #008', image: Welthy8, Owner: 'Brens', id: 8 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #009', image: Welthy9, Owner: 'Jack', id: 9 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #010', image: Welthy10, Owner: 'Sandra', id: 10 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #011', image: Welthy11, Owner: 'Pepe', id: 11 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #012', image: Welthy12, Owner: 'Luis', id: 12 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #013', image: Welthy13, Owner: 'Jose', id: 13 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #014', image: Welthy14, Owner: 'Sofy', id: 14 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #015', image: Welthy15, Owner: 'July', id: 15 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #016', image: Welthy16, Owner: 'Brens', id: 16 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #017', image: Welthy17, Owner: 'Brens', id: 17 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #018', image: Welthy18, Owner: 'Sofy', id: 18 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #019', image: Welthy19, Owner: 'Laura', id: 19 },
        {name: 'Welthy Moles #020', image: Welthy20, Owner: 'Charls', id: 20 }
    ];
```

I have this map config that shows all of them by id, but don't know how to show only the ones that match mole.Owner = currentAccount

```
  {moles.map((mole) => (
                <div className='mole-preview' key={mole.id}>
                    <h1> #{mole.id} </h1>
                    <img src={mole.image} alt="mole" />
                    <h2> {mole.name} </h2>
                </div>
            ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the filter method:

```
  {moles.filter(mole => mole.Owner === currentAccount).map((mole) => (
                <div className='mole-preview' key={mole.id}>
                    <h1> #{mole.id} </h1>
                    <img src={mole.image} alt="mole" />
                    <h2> {mole.name} </h2>
                </div>
            ))}
```

This way you're creating an array where each item in the array is a mole who's owner is the same value as the `currentAccount` variable.

Comment: this helped me solved the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the moles based on the `currentAccount` and then use that filtered array in the template.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const moles = [
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #001', image: 'Welthy1', Owner: 'Luis', id: 1 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #002', image: 'Welthy2', Owner: 'Pepe', id: 2 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #003', image: 'Welthy3', Owner: 'July', id: 3 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #004', image: 'Welthy4', Owner: 'Pepe', id: 4 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #005', image: 'Welthy5', Owner: 'Lola', id: 5 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #006', image: 'Welthy6', Owner: 'Luis', id: 6 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #007', image: 'Welthy7', Owner: 'Raul', id: 7 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #008', image: 'Welthy8', Owner: 'Brens', id: 8 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #009', image: 'Welthy9', Owner: 'Jack', id: 9 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #010', image: 'Welthy10', Owner: 'Sandra', id: 10 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #011', image: 'Welthy11', Owner: 'Pepe', id: 11 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #012', image: 'Welthy12', Owner: 'Luis', id: 12 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #013', image: 'Welthy13', Owner: 'Jose', id: 13 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #014', image: 'Welthy14', Owner: 'Sofy', id: 14 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #015', image: 'Welthy15', Owner: 'July', id: 15 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #016', image: 'Welthy16', Owner: 'Brens', id: 16 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #017', image: 'Welthy17', Owner: 'Brens', id: 17 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #018', image: 'Welthy18', Owner: 'Sofy', id: 18 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #019', image: 'Welthy19', Owner: 'Laura', id: 19 },
  {name: 'Welthy Moles #020', image: 'Welthy20', Owner: 'Charls', id: 20 }
];

const currentAccount = 'Pepe';

const res = moles.filter((obj) => obj.Owner === currentAccount);

console.log(res);
```